# Minecraft Login Issues (Unable to find valid certification path)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I haven't been able to  play Minecraft on my Macbook Pro for around 4 days.

Whenever I try to login to my account, this is what appears:

> Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers.
>
> Please make sure that you are online and Minecraft is not blocked.
>
> *(SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)*

I have no idea what to do. I've searched on Google, but there was nothing about it, and tried contacting Mojang support, but they weren't any help either.

Answer (score 3):

**What I would try is this:**

1. Turn off your firewall

   Your firewall might be blocking your Minecraft from connecting to the internet, which is causing your error
2. Make sure you are actually connected to an internet

   Depending on what kind of internet you use, some internet hosting parties won't allow access to the Minecraft authentication servers.  Things like HotSpots may no longer work also.
3. Re-install Minecraft

   One of the most common fixes is to just remove Minecraft from your computer and re-download it.  Make sure to backup your worlds first if you have any.
4. Login to [Minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net/)

   Make sure your account is active, by logging into your account on their website